# Association in sequelize not working.(it is not creating the column containing the foreign k)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I created two tables Assets and Users in my database. But when I try to create association between them the column containing the foreign key won't be created in the table. Below are my codes for both models and index.js.

index.js

```
   
const dbConfig = require('../config/db.config')

const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')


const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DATABASE, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
    port: 3306,
    host: dbConfig.HOST,
    dialect: dbConfig.DIALECT
})


const db = {};
db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.models = {};
db.models.Employees = require('./Employees')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
db.models.Assets = require('./Assets')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
db.models.Users = require('./Users')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);




module.exports = db
```

Users.js

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
        firstname: DataTypes.STRING,
        middlename: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastname: DataTypes.STRING,
        address: DataTypes.STRING,
        Role: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        phoneNo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        department: DataTypes.STRING,
        room: DataTypes.INTEGER,
       

        
    })

    return Users;
}
```

Assets.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Assets = sequelize.define('Assets', {
        category: DataTypes.STRING,
        manufacturer: DataTypes.STRING,
        model: DataTypes.STRING,
        serialNo: DataTypes.JSON,
        datePurchased: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
        quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        cost: DataTypes.STRING,

        image: DataTypes.BLOB,

      
    }) 

    
    Assets.associate = (models) => {
        Assets.hasOne(models.Users, {

            onDelete: "cascade",
        })
    }

    return Assets;
}
```

I saw a similar question in and tried what worked for them which is putting the db.sync before route registration in the index.js of my server but didn't work.

Comment: I don't see  a bit of code where you call `associate` of registered models